# I can't install Winusb?

Tags: package-management, dependencies

I try to install Winusb and this comes up:

```
Package dependencies cannot be resolved: This error could be caused by
required additional software packages which are missing or not
installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software
packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.

Details: The following packages have unmet dependencies:

winusb: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.3.6-6~) but 2.15-0ubuntu20 is to be
installed Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.7.2-2ubuntu1 is to be
installed Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.4.0) but 4.7.2-2ubuntu1 is to be
installed Depends: libwxbase2.8-0 (>= 2.8.12.1) but it is not going to
be installed Depends: libwxgtk2.8-0 (>= 2.8.12.1) but it is not going
to be installed Depends: ntfs-3g (>= 1:2011) but
1:2012.1.15AR.5-4ubuntu3 is to be installed
```

I don't know how to fix this or make a windows bootable usb drive, please help.

Answer (score 2):

Try activating all software sources in Software & Updates:

[image]

Comment: u da real mvp!!